# Problem in destroy java process with ProcessBuilder()

Tags: java

Hi I have a problem to run an external process in java 8.
Basically I jave to run ffplay from my java code, and seems that the .destroy() method doesn't work if the external process have child processes.

My code is:
'''

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder();
builder.command().add("/usr/bin/fplay");
builder.command().add(".........."); // my args
builder.environment().put("LD_LIBRARY_PATH", myCustomLibraryPath);
Process process = builder.start();

// After 
process.destroy();
process.destroyForcibly();
```

'''
But even after doing the destroy() and destroyForcibly() the ffplay window remains open.
I tried to use Runtime.getRuntime().exec(......) instead of ProcessBuilder and in this case seems that the destroy method closes the ffplay window. But I don't know how to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH in Runtime.

Is there anyone who can help me terminate the ffplay process with ProcessBuilder or setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH to Runtime.getRuntime().exec(......)?

Comment: To set envvar(s) in `Runtime.exec` use [one of the overloads that takes envp e.g.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec-java.lang.String:A-java.lang.String:A-) but it uses the same `Process` implementation underneath so I doubt destroy will work any better.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, The strange thing is what I described in the post. Seems that the problem is only with the scripts.

Comment: Yes, running a script can create different process trees than running a program directly, which also makes killilng it very different, depending on the shell used and details of the script. If that was your question, maybe you should have asked about it.  Stack is not a discussion group or chat room; you are supposed to put the question -- singular -- in the question.

Comment: @Masso did you ever find a solution to this issue? I'm facing the exact same problem and I thought maybe I was just doing something wrong. My code is nearly identical to yours.

Answer (score 2):

Last week i had the probelm to kill my batch script which i started with the ProcessBuilder.
My solution was

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM cmd.exe")
```

Answer (score 0):

@dave_thompson_085
I noticed a strange thing, the problem that destroy doesn't work is only with scripts. Let me explain better, if I do this:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder();
builder.command().add("ffplay");
builder.command().add("/videos/TEST.mp4");
Process process = builder.start();
```

the destroy() method closes the ffplay window. But if I create a script named myScript.sh with only this line in it:

```
ffplay /videos/TEST.mp4
```

and I do:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder();
builder.command().add("myScript.sh");
Process process = builder.start()
```

The destroy() method doesn't close the ffplay window.